# Python QWebView - Screenshot with a delay

Tags: python, qt4, qwebview

I need a python script to take a screenshot of a webpage. I have the following code that works well:

```
class Screenshot(QWebView):
def __init__(self):
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    QWebView.__init__(self)
    self._loaded = False
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)

def capture(self, url, output_file):
    self.load(QUrl(url))
    self.wait_load()

    # set to webpage size
    frame = self.page().mainFrame()
    self.page().setViewportSize(QSize(900,1600))

    # render image
    image = QImage(self.page().viewportSize(), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
    painter = QPainter(image)
    frame.render(painter)
    painter.end()
    print 'saving', output_file
    image.save(output_file)

def wait_load(self, delay=0):
    # process app events until page loaded

    while not self._loaded:

        self.app.processEvents()
        time.sleep(delay)
    self._loaded = False

def _loadFinished(self, result):
    self._loaded = True
```

However the screenshot is taken immediately after the page loads, the pages i am trying to screenshot have a JS interface that takes about 20 seconds to load everything (Large graphs). How would I delay the browser?

I know I can't do this with time.sleep() as it freezes the thread including the web browser, resulting the same image, so I know i need to use a QTimer() but I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
class Screenshot(QWebView):
def __init__(self):
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    QWebView.__init__(self)

def capture(self, url, output_file):

    self._file = output_file
    # set to webpage size
    frame = self.page().mainFrame()
    self.page().setViewportSize(QSize(900,1600))

    self.timerScreen = QTimer()
    self.timerScreen.setInterval(30000)
    self.timerScreen.setSingleShot(True)
    self.timerScreen.timeout.connect(self.grab)
    self.loadFinished.connect(self.timerScreen.start)

    self.load(QUrl(url))

def grab(self):

    # render image
    image = QImage(self.page().viewportSize(), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
    painter = QPainter(image)
    frame.render(painter)
    painter.end()
    print 'saving', self._file
    image.save(self._file)
```

Instead this causes calls to Screenshot.capture() to return instantly and no screenshot is take.

Also I can't use the app.exec_() method because this caused my application to hang, as this is part of a bigger headless command line only program this is a no-go.

Any input is appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: did you manage to do it? I am with the same problem